# How to Delete Rows Based on Dates

Tags: date, record

I have a table with 6000+ rows. Entries are in this format:
|Vehicle  |  Part Type | Installed Date | Part Serial Number |
|---------|  ----------|--------------- | ------------------ |
|   1     |     A      |    2017-8-17   |     0001           |
|  22     |     A      |    2010-10-13  |     0001           |
|   4     |     A      |    2017-05-05  |     0001           |
|   7     |     A      |    2020-07-11  |     0001           |
|  14     |     B      |    2017-07-30  |     B342           |
|   9     |     B      |    2019-04-22  |     B342           |
|  78     |     B      |    2021-01-06  |     B342           |

I have parts that have been removed from service and put back into service at a later date on
different vehicles.  So I'd like my table to have only the most current info so I can quickly
identify which vehicle has which part, looking something like this:

| Vehicle | Part Type | Installed Date | Part Serial Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | A | 2020-07-11 | 0001 |
| 78 | B | 2021-01-06 | B342 |

Any ideas?

Having difficult time using max and delete and other tools to remove unwanted rows

Comment: Please provide a valid set of sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but you could just do a simple delete statement

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE Installed_Date <= '2020-07-11'
```

Comment: But my dates will be different in each row...in my example Part A's latest install was 7/11/20, but other parts will have other dates, some BEFORE 7/11/20 and some after 7/11/20. I need to compare all dates for just Part A Serial # 0001 and then select the row with only the latest. Then do the same for Part B with Serial number B342. But there are many more Part As and Part Bs with different serial numbers.